# Is linear and/or quadratic probing ever used in the real world?

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

I'm in school, and we've been learning about hashing. For open addressing, we've learned about the three probing methods: linear probing, quadratic probing, and double hashing.

On a similar question here, Jim Mischel answered:
"[...] You should also note that in practice, as long as the load factor is reasonable and you have a good hashing function, there is almost no real difference in the performance of these (linear, quadratic, double hashing) and other open addressing schemes like cuckoo hashing, etc".

As far as I know, Java's HashMap is implemented using separate chaining with a linked list. **Is it common for people to write their own implementation using linear/quadratic probing, instead of using Java's default implementation?** And considering what Jim said, wouldn't people still use double hashing over linear/quadratic probing if they want open addressing?

Comment: IdentityHashMap uses linear probing for example: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html. This is supposed to result in better locality and hence performance, in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I know, Java's HashMap is implemented using separate chaining with a linked list.

This is correct. However, Java has [another hash map implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) <sup>*</sup> called `IdentityHashMap<K,V>`, which uses linear probing instead:

> Implementation note: This is a simple linear-probe hash table, as described for example in texts by Sedgewick and Knuth. The array alternates holding keys and values. (This has better locality for large tables than does using separate arrays.) For many JRE implementations and operation mixes, this class will yield better performance than HashMap (which uses chaining rather than linear-probing).

I don't know of framework implementations of hash tables with quadratic probing. To me, the most obvious reason to go to quadratic probing in my own implementation would be avoiding "hash clusters" when hash buckets next to each other are filled with data, while other contiguous areas of the bucket array remain empty. Ultimately, though, this is a compensation for a less-than-ideal hash function on your original objects, because in theory the clustering shouldn't happen.

<sup>*</sup> Strictly speaking, `IdentityHashMap` is not a proper implementation of hash map, because it breaks the contract by using identity rather than equality comparison.